# Does PLayN work with sockets?

Tags: sockets, playn

I have a java application that uses sockets to connect to it's server. I want to wrap it with PlayN but i can't find out the way to make sockets work if there is one at all.
There IS the way, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

PlayN applications can be compiled to JavaScript and run in the browser. There are no browser APIs for reading and writing sockets directly. There is a WebSockets API, which is presently very primitive, but at least accomplishes asynchronous message passing between client and server over a persistent connection.

You will not be able to "wrap" an application that uses plain Java sockets. You can create an abstraction layer for your network and route the socket communications over WebSockets, but that's the best you can do if you want the game to run using the HTML5 backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interrested in HTML as backend but only platforms that do support sockets in one way or another you could create an abstraction for your network communication in the core project and implement it with the different platform specific sockets in each platform specific project. In HTML you are out of luck unless you can settle with web sockets.